# Dependency injection in a custom class

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I have a custom module (my_module); Inside this module I have a custom class (MyClass), where I want to use a Drupal service (file_system).

This is my code.

#### src/MyClass.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem;

class MyClass {
  public function __construct(FileSystem $file_system) {
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('file_system')
    );
  }
}
```

When I instantiate this class (in a controller for example), I get an error.

```
$my_class = new MyClass();
```

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\my_module\MyClass::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem, none given

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DI requires a bit more effort than that - you haven't told the system about your class; the DI container doesn't know that you've called `new MyClass()`, and it can't get involved.

You need to create a [Service](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133171), which you can make depend on other available services, instances of which will be passed to your class using the static `create` method pattern you're already using.

In this case, that's probably as simple as providing your mymodule.services.yml and adding:

```
my_service:
    class: Drupal\my_module\MyClass
    arguments: ['@file_system']
```

When you've correctly registered the class with the system, you'll get an instance of it like so (if you need it in a global function):

```
$foo = Drupal::service('my_service');
```

Or if you're consuming it in a container aware class, then you can inject it just like any other service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In $foo, i will get an instance of MyClass ?

If i write :

    $foo1 = Drupal::service('my_service');
    $foo2 = Drupal::service('my_service');

I will get 2 distinct instances ?

Comment: Symfony services are singletons as far as I know, you probably want to create a [factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) if you need different instances

Comment: Ok so, declaring a class as a service is the only way of using DI insite it ?

Comment: As far as utility classes go, yes. Controllers are different, for example

Comment: @Clive how does the form system does it? I mean when creating a custom configuration  form the create method can have `$container->get('current_user'),` as DI. But is ConfigFormBase a service ? or how is actually being injected?

Comment: So we cannot add a service to a custom class like we do for a controller or Form?

Comment: No @Binny, there are specific mechanisms in place to make those things work with DI. The quickest way to get DI in a custom class is to make it a service

Comment: This was helpful. For injecting into a plugin into a class that extends ProcessPluginBase you can also implement the ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.

Comment: Good example of this https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-in-plugin-block