# How do I instantiate a custom class with dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection

I am relatively fresh to the DI party and am struggling to get my head around how exactly to use Dependency Injection.
I understand that I can pass requirements as part of a service, but what about in my own class?

Say I have the below class where I want the language manager service to be injected:

```
class Foo implements ContainerInjectionInterface {

  protected $languageManager; 

  public function __construct(LanguageManagerInterface $languageManager) {
    $this->languageManager = $languageManager;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('language_manager')
    );
  }
}
```

When I call `new Foo()` I am required to pass an instance of LanguageManagerInterface. That makes sense in terms of a normal constructor method, but that would require me to instantiate the class like the below:

```
$languageManager = \Drupal::service('language_manager');
$foo = new Foo($languageManager)
```

That just doesn't feel right to me.

Is there something I am missing, or would this class always have to be a service to take advantage of dependency injection?

Comment: You can't use dependency injection in your custom class without defining it as a service. The question has been answered in more detail here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195165/dependency-injection-in-a-custom-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency injection in a custom class](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195165/dependency-injection-in-a-custom-class)

Comment: Yes! And for a living example you can see it in https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twigsuggest/-/blob/8.x-1.x/twigsuggest.services.yml (the service) and https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twigsuggest/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Utils/HelperFunctions.php (the class).

Answer (score 3):

A class implementing `ContainerInjectionInterface` is instantiated by calling the factory method create().

See *Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver*

```
/**
 * Implements the class resolver interface supporting class names and services.
 */
class ClassResolver implements ClassResolverInterface, ContainerAwareInterface {
  use DependencySerializationTrait;
  use ContainerAwareTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInstanceFromDefinition($definition) {
    if ($this->container->has($definition)) {
      $instance = $this->container->get($definition);
    }
    else {
      if (!class_exists($definition)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Class "%s" does not exist.', $definition));
      }

      if (is_subclass_of($definition, 'Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface')) {
        $instance = $definition::create($this->container);
      }
      else {
        $instance = new $definition();
      }
    }

    if ($instance instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
      $instance->setContainer($this->container);
    }

    return $instance;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @4k4. So you are saying I should do `$foo = Foo::create()`? When I do that with the example above I need to pass a ContianerInterface. If thats right, should this be obtained from `\Drupal::getContainer()` or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know in which context you use the class. If it is a controller then it gets instantiated by the code above automatically. If you want to instantiate `Foo` in custom OOP code then inject the class resolver or procedural use `$foo = \Drupal::classResolver(Foo::class);`

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, the factory design pattern is the most appropriate way to instantiate an object (of a custom class with dependency injection).

From D.O.'s documentation:

> [Instantiation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/object-oriented-code#instantiation)
>
> Creating classes directly is discouraged. Instead, use a factory function that creates the appropriate object and returns it. This provides two benefits:
>
> - It provides a layer of indirection, as the function may be written to return a different object (with the same interface) in different circumstances as appropriate.
> - PHP does not allow class constructors to be chained, but does allow the return value from a function or method to be chained.

A code example from a D.O. core issue ([[PP-1] Add a factory method to create FileStorage instances](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2657548)) shows how one would go about doing that in Drupal. So, for your example that would be something like this:

> Service Definition
>
> ```
> foo_factory:
>   class: Drupal\your_module\FooFactory  
>   arguments: ['@language_manager']
> ```
>
> and the related instantiation code:
>
> ```
> $fooFactory = \Drupal::service('foo_factory');
> $foo = $fooFactory->create();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the class in question is correct. All you need is correctly call the object method. To do that - drupal has special mechanism - class resolver.
Here is how to initialize your object correctly:

```
use Foo;

\Drupal::classResolver(Foo::class)->yourClassMethod($some_arguments_from_hook_or_preprocess);
```

[Read more about class resolver](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AclassResolver/8.6.x)

Comment: Important to note from the documentation:

"This is to be used in procedural code"

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis right. Thanks